# How to install chaincode using fabric sdk (fabric-client)?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-js, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-go

Based on the package definition listed here https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/master/tutorial-chaincode-lifecycle.html

```
const package_request = {
     chaincodeType: 'golang',
     goPath: '/gopath',
     chaincodePath: '/path/to/code',
     metadataPath: '/path/to/metadata'
}
```

Where do I put the byte array of my chaincode go (golang) codes which is sitting in my laptop?  Also not sure what `chaincodePath` and `metadataPath` are for?  Are they path in the fabric system?

Basically, I don't know how to load my golang source codes (chaincode) to the request to install the chaincode.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 2):

The `chaincodePath` is the directory containing the actual chaincode file (say `chainCode.go`) and the `metadataPath` is the directory that may contain metadata files, e.g. index files if needed by your chaincode.

Answer (score 2):

For `fabric-go-sdk` you can refer to [chainHeroExample](https://chainhero.io/2018/06/tutorial-build-blockchain-app-v1-1-0/#make-your-first-blockchain-network). check `main.go` and `setup.go` files.

Below is the snippet of `main.go` file.

```
func main() {
    // Definition of the Fabric SDK properties
    fSetup := blockchain.FabricSetup{
        // Network parameters
        OrdererID: "orderer.firstproject.com",

        // Channel parameters
        ChannelID:     "mychannel",
        ChannelConfig: "/c/Projects/Go/src/github.com/hyperledger/firstproject/firstproject-network/artifacts/channel.tx",

        // Chaincode parameters
        ChainCodeID:     "firstproject",
        ChaincodeGoPath: "/c/Projects/Go",
        ChaincodePath:   "github.com/hyperledger/firstproject/chaincode/",
        OrgAdmin:        "Admin",
        OrgName:         "org1",
        ConfigFile:      "config.yaml",

        // User parameters
        UserName: "User1",
    }

    // Initialization of the Fabric SDK from the previously set properties
    err := fSetup.Initialize()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Unable to initialize the Fabric SDK: %v\n", err)
        return
    }
    // Close SDK
    defer fSetup.CloseSDK()

    // Install and instantiate the chaincode
    err = fSetup.InstallAndInstantiateCC()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Unable to install and instantiate the chaincode: %v\n", err)
        return
    }

    // Query the chaincode
    response, err := fSetup.QueryHello()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Unable to query hello on the chaincode: %v\n", err)
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("Response from the query hello: %s\n", response)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

To install the chaincode you have to use the following method:

```
installCCReq := resmgmt.InstallCCRequest{
                Name: ccName,
                Path: ccPath, 
                Version: ccVersion,
                Package: ccPkg}
```

Here is the complete [example](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/blob/master/test/integration/e2e/orgs/multiple_orgs_test.go) and here is the complete [documentation](https://godoc.org/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/pkg/client/resmgmt#Client.InstallCC)